# How to access my user activity on other users' pages or fan pages using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, relationship, fan-page

I would like to find any of my own activity (post, comment, share, etc.) on another user's page or a fan page. That is, *obtain a list of all the comments, posts and whatnot that I have made on user XYZ's page, or on SOMETVSHOW's page*.

Is that possible at all? I've looked at the different relations that are accessible using the Graph API, but there seems to be no direct way to get this data.

One way to do this is to collect ALL of my own activity and then run this data through a filter that would extract just the comments, post, etc. that I left on a certain user's page or fan page. But that is not really efficient, especially if you have (like me) a very large amount of data to capture in the first place.

Also, I could go the other way and grab ALL of that user's or fan page's activity and the filter out my own posts and comments, but likewise, this would take an eternity and produce huge amounts of data that need to be processed.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: When I said "huge amounts" and "very large amounts" of data, I am aware that it's really not that much data, but what I meant to express that it would take a long time to get this data using the Graph API :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this pretty easily via FQL:

```
SELECT post_id, type, message, created_time, attachment FROM stream 
  WHERE source_id = PAGE_ID AND actor_id = me() LIMIT 200
```

You will have the normal limitations of the `stream` table to deal with, so you may have to page back through these results to get everything you are looking for.

Comment: Oh wow, I never looked at FQL before; didn't now this was possible. Thank you very much. I'll try this!